# Placing Ruby `require` outside of a module definition?

Tags: ruby

In Ruby, is it OK to place a `require` statement outside of a module definition? Will the `require`'d module still be available inside classes nested in the module?

For example, is this:

```
require 'baz'
module Foo
  class Bar
    # some code using Baz
  end
end
```

the same as this?

```
module Foo
  require 'baz'
  class Bar
    # some code using Baz
  end
end
```

and the same as this?

```
module Foo
  class Bar
    require 'baz'
    # some code using Baz
  end
end
```

Comment: Yes, it's okay to place it outside.

Comment: @DaveNewton What is the best practice ?

Comment: @ArupRakshit i've almost exclusively seen `require`s at the top of files. I think it's a great way to see all the dependencies directly.

Comment: @p11y Yes... me too. But just asking if anything hidden are there, which I don't know

Comment: I must say it is good question.. Indeed +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put `require` anywhere. As you can see in the documentation [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Kernel.html#method-i-require), constants and globals from the required file are always added the the global namespace. Best practice is generally to use require outside of any nesting, but some gems take advantage of the fact that it available anywhere to conditionally require files based on ruby logic, i.e

```
if some_boolean
  require 'file'
end
```

Answer (score 2):

`require` simply runs the code in the file. It is completely irrelevant where you put it. It depends on the code in the file, what happens, not where `require` is called.